# How to convert from CIE XYZ to Munsell and back in R

Tags: r, package, color-theory

I am trying to implement a conversion from the CIE XYZ color space to the Munsell specifications, using the package `munsellinterpol` in R (to my knowledge, this package is based on the Kubelka-Munk toolbox that is also available, e.g., in Matlab).

Anyway, converting from Munsell to XYZ works without problems:

```
MunsellToXYZ("2.22Y 3/9")
# $X
# [1] 7.062125

# $Y
# [1] 6.391178

# $Z
# [1] -0.4203379

# $Status.ind
# [1] 1
```

However, going the other way doesn't seem to work:

```
XYZtoMunsell(c(7.062125, 6.391178, -0.4203379))
# $Status.ind
# [1] 4

# $Status.dist
# NULL

# $Status.num
# NULL
```

Also, the first time the function is called, R outputs a weird error:

```
PLEASE NOTE:  As of version 0.3-5, no degenerate (zero area) 
regions are returned with the "Qt" option since the R 
code removes them from the triangulation. 
See help("delaunayn").
```

I know that the functions utilize some kind of optimization to approximate a good mapping based on the Munsell renotation data. And I do realize that not all colors may have a good Munsell mapping. But I would expect the functions to at least work forwards and backwards, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Indeed, not even the example given in the documentation works:

```
XYZtoMunsell(c(0.310897, 0.306510, 74.613450))
# $Status.ind
# [1] 4

# $Status.dist
# NULL

# $Status.num
# NULL
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Running through the source code I can see that XYZtoMunsell calls xyYtoMunsell which in turn calls IsWithinMacAdamLimits which returns FALSE.  This results in $Status.ind being assigned a value of 4.  
See https://github.com/cran/munsellinterpol/blob/master/R/munsellinterpol.R for the source code.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that makes sense. So, an error code of 4 seems to mean that the converted color is not within the MacAdams limits. But then, what's the thing about the triangulation error? Not even the example given in the documentation works. Indeed, the error is given for a big range of XYZ values (did some experiments in the meantime). Could it be that some fundamental R code was silently modified?

Comment: IsWithinMacAdamLimits calls the routine tsearchn which "returns the index of the tetrahedron in the Delaunay tessellation that contains the input colour.  If no tetrahedron contains that colour, then tsearchn returns NaN."  I have not used the Munsell color space since the late '80s when I was at Eastman Kodak so I don't know if these XYZ values (i.e. (0.310897, 0.306510, 74.613450)) are valid.  I suggest testing another resource/library such as the Kubelka-Munk toolbox in MATLAB for verification.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I kinda expected the problem to be a failing triangulation. Unfortunately, since I left the research institute, where I was working a few years ago, I have no access to MATLAB anymore. I'm happily using R now, so I don't know, if the error is just in the package. However, even calls like `sRGBtoMunsell(c(23,45,67))` fail, but really shouldn't, so I'm guessing it's the package... (or some change in some fundamental R code)

Comment: We have the same issue with Colour (https://github.com/colour-science/colour): ValueError: "[ 0.54186633  0.49038557  0.06391178]" is not within "MacAdam" limits for illuminant "C"!

Answer (score 1):

On Jun 6 2018, the `munsellinterpol` package received a big rewrite.
The examples:

```
XYZtoMunsell(c(7.062125, 6.391178, -0.4203379))
XYZtoMunsell(c(0.310897, 0.306510, 74.613450)) 
sRGBtoMunsell(c(23,45,67))
```

now it work OK (I checked v. 2.5-1).

The first one: `XYZ=c(7.062125, 6.391178, -0.4203379)` 
is outside the MacAdam limits because `$Z<0$`, which is equivalent to `$x+y>1$`.
But `XYZtoMunsell()` is not as strict now and does not care.
The published Munsell `HVC -> xy` lookup table has many points where `$x+y>1$`.